# curl передать пароль при авторизации

Tags: curl, auth, router

```
curl --digest -u user:pass http://192.168.0.1
401 Unauthorized
```

Почему не передается пароль при авторизации?
Если ввести пароль вручную, то авторизация проходит успешно.

```
curl --digest -u user http://192.168.0.1
Enter host password for user 'user':
```

Comment: Пропробуйте так `curl http://username:password@api.somesite.com/test/blah?something=123`

Comment: В пароле есть "@" поэтому curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 12345@192.168.0.1 Пробовал так curl --url http://192.168.0.1 -K- <<< "--user user:pass" 401 Unauthorized